# CentOS : Is it possible to get information about the active directory?

Tags: linux, active-directory, group-policy

I have a domain with several Windows and CentOS machines. I was wondering how to get information from a Linux machine about the active directory.
 I would like to be able to get the list of GPOs applied to the domain without having to set SAMBA as Active Directory. Is that possible ?

EDIT : I saw on the Internet that it was possible to install Powershell on Centos machines so I thought maybe I could get the list of the GPOs with Powershell but I am not sure this is an efficient solution... Any other idea ?

EDIT : I found out that the Powershell commands implemented for unix are not enough to be able to get the gpos...
I found this https://www.mankier.com/5/sssd-ad#Description but I am not sure I understand how it works... For example if I enable ad_gpo_map_interactive(), will it enable Allow log on locally in my active directory ?

Comment: In Windows, in order to retrieve GPOs, you must be joined to that domain, or in the same forest with visibility into the domain of interest.  I don't believe you would be able to do it from a *nix without being logged in.

Comment: Given that you've had four months to research, perhaps you can edit the question to include some of the things you've tried.  You should also only ask one question per question, and make each short and readable.  You can make more questions (very specific questions are best), and you can also answer your own questions.  Someone else may ask the same question in the future, and you can save them the same hassle you're going through right now with some well-written questions and answers.

Comment: My machine is joined into the domain. I just do not understand how I can get information from the Active Directory and more specifically information about the GPOs.